# Azure logic apps : Setting Workflow name dynamically to call a existing logic app(Nested Logic app)

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way where we can update the workflows dynamically while calling a Child logic app as:

- Normal workflow Configuration is as below:
  [image]
- What i want to achieve is as below, either using Properties, Variables anything which updates the 
  workflow at runtime, i tried to use as below :

[image]

- When i try to save as above it results as error as : Failed to save
  logic app Test. The workflow run action
  /providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/@{variables('WorkflowName')}' of
  type 'EventGrid' has a malformed property 'host.workflow.id'.**The
  expected format is
  'subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows**

Comment: i think you can't. this has to be set statically

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported. There is a **[feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32849239-allow-calling-functions-and-nested-logic-apps-usin)** which I believe will address this as well that you could up vote for it to gain more traction.

As for a workaround, instead of using the **[Workflow Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#workflow-action)**, you could simply use the **[HTTP Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#http-action)** to trigger your other Logic Apps.

You can use the **[Workflows - List Callback Url ARM REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/listcallbackurl)** to fetch the URL of your Logic App to call. **[Using Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity)**, you can securely fetch the Trigger URLs from ARM and dynamically call other Logic Apps.

Comment: Thank you Dixit,

With regards to the same, in Batch Connector we have workflows property which doesn't have Callback Url, How will we call those logic apps ?